# Unable to show custom markers while using clustering

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have an issue with custom markers on google maps while using clustering.

I managed to get clustering work in my app but instead of showing my custom markers on the map it shows a default red markers. (before implementing clustering custom images worked fine)

I have tried the below but it is not working:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
        if (marker.userData is POIItem) {

            marker.icon = UIImage(named: "sightseeingMarker")
}
```

Also didTap cluster method is not working, app is simply crashing.

```
func clusterManager(_ clusterManager: GMUClusterManager, didTap cluster: GMUCluster) -> Bool {

        print("Cluster tapped")
        let newCamera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: cluster.position,
                                                 zoom: mapView.camera.zoom + 1)
        let update = GMSCameraUpdate.setCamera(newCamera)
        mapView.moveCamera(update)

        return false
    }
```

Would be really helpful if somebody could lead me thru and help with these issues.

Comment: Please go through this link https://dev.to/onmyway133/how-to-do-clustering-with-google-maps-in-ios-5on

Comment: Implemented the same but does not work.

Comment: Please see related questions and let us know if these solutions work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45394188/11742502 (which links to: [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45374164/11742502) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46348627/11742502))